# How do I manually populate .ninja_log with information preventing unnecesary rebuilding files?

Tags: ninja, build-system

After moving files around and adapting `build.ninja` (without changing filesystem timestamps), it tries to build everything again.

I discovered `.ninja_log` and removed it, but it did not prevent the rebuild. In fact, it seems like missing entries from Ninja log causes it to be more cautious and issue more rebuilds.

I tried `ninja -t restat`, but it seems to do no-op in case of missing Ninja log.

How do generate such `build.ninja` that next Ninja has minimum rebuilds (preferring existing files) and only new changes trigger rebuilds? Is there something like `--dry-run`, but that writes `.ninja_log` as if it was not `--dry-run`?

Answer (score 0):

## Hacky version

1. Modify Ninja source code with a kludge patch like this

```
diff --git a/src/ninja.cc b/src/ninja.cc
index 9ae53de..616fce7 100644
--- a/src/ninja.cc
+++ b/src/ninja.cc
@@ -1257,12 +1257,12 @@ bool NinjaMain::OpenBuildLog(bool recompact_only) {
     return success;
   }

-  if (!config_.dry_run) {
+  //if (!config_.dry_run) {
     if (!build_log_.OpenForWrite(log_path, *this, &err)) {
       Error("opening build log: %s", err.c_str());
       return false;
     }
-  }
+  //}

   return true;
 }
```

2. Run modified `ninja -v -n`. Unlike normal Ninja, it would not be real dry run, it would save the logfile.
3. `touch` files in the needed order, if needed.
4. Run `ninja -t restat`

Now it should skip at least some steps.

---

Shall I try to contribute a dedicated tool like `ninja -t bless` to make this approach proper part of Ninja?

Comment: Hey Vi, did you ever got around to create `bless`?

Comment: @Zeta Not yet. Recently I needed this, but instead ended up implementing a special environment variable that makes my commands executed by `ninja` skip steps and just touch output files.